# Circumvent deletion of screen session and nohup processes on logout

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, nohup

Everywhere I look I see that `screen` is for keeping a session open so that you can come back to it after disconnection.  But this doesn't seem to be the case for a system that I `ssh` to.  Do I understand correctly, that the sysadmins have crippled nohup and screen?  Is there a way to circumvent this?

Here is a test I did (perhaps the problem is me):

```
mira1:~> screen -S test  COMMENT: I did ctrl-a ctrl-d
[detached from 54211.test]
mira1:~> logout
Connection to mira1.**** closed.
me:~ me$ ssh me@mira1.***

Last login: Tue Feb  9 23:21:57 2016 from client*****
mira1:~> screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-me.
```

Edit:
The screen is still there after detaching it and before logging out.  As in:

```
mira1:~> screen -S test
[detached from 59923.test]
mira1:~> ls -ltr /var/run/screen/S-me/
total 0
prw------- 1 me URP_dse 0 Feb  9 23:39 59923.test
mira1:~>
```

Edit 2 for Gile's questions:
Here is `ssh` session #1

```
mira1:~> screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    59923.test  (09/02/16 23:39:26) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-me.

mira1:~> screen -r
[detached from 59923.test]
```

`ssh` session #2

```
mira1:~> screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    59923.test  (09/02/16 23:39:26) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-me.
```

`ssh` sesssion #1 again

```
mira1:~> logout
Connection to mira1.**** closed.
client-10-129-225-10:~ me$
```

`ssh` session #2 again (screen gone)

```
mira1:~> screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-me.
```

Comment: Show us `ls -ltr /var/run/screen/` after you detach the screen.

Comment: If you start two SSH sessions, start screen in one, detach and log out from that session, can you still attach to the screen in the other session? If you can't, what happens if you first attach in the second session, then log out from the session where you started screen? What kind of system is it? What shell are you using, is there anything in `.logout` or `.bash_logout` or whatever applies to your shell?

Comment: Gilles I'll look into those.  meantime, why does it say "total 0" when there is 1 item in the list?  total 0
prw------- 1 me URP_dse 0 Feb  9 23:39 59923.test

Comment: system is Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie).  .logout contains source X, where X is an empty file.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493024/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345292/ .

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that screen's `autodetach` feature is turned off:

> autodetach on|off
>  
>   Sets whether screen will automatically detach upon hangup, which  saves
>   all  your running programs until they are resumed with a `screen -r` command.  When turned off, a hangup signal will terminate screen  and  all
>   the processes it contains. Autodetach is on by default.

Assuming that the setting is not in your `$HOME/.screenrc`, the place to look would be in the system's file, e.g., `/etc/screenrc`.

Another possibility is that the remote machine is configured (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) to disconnect idle users.  See for example

- [How to disconnect idle (after few minutes of inactivity) ssh sessions automatically](http://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-disconnect-idle-after-few-minutes-of-inactivity-ssh-sessions-automatically/)
- [How do I terminate all idle incoming ssh connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137632/how-do-i-terminate-all-idle-incoming-ssh-connections)

But in that case, there is not much that you could do about it.

Comment: So you are saying this could be a problem? :)
mira1:~> grep -e "autodetach"  /etc/screenrc
#autodetach off

Comment: wait, no that's a comment.  I added "autodetach on" to my .screenrc and still get the same behaviour.

Comment: hmmm, /etc/ssh/sshd_config is present, but no ClientAlive* present.

Comment: Just wanted to say, this fixed the issue for me. Thanks